# Is there a way to make the timezone correlate to the user's timezone

Tags: django

As of now I have the timezone set to my own timezone, but is there a way to make the timezone change based on the user that is browsing the site? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/timezones/#time-zones

Comment: Did you set both `USE_TZ` and `USE_L10N` on `True`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When support for time zones is enabled, Django stores datetime information in UTC in the database, uses time-zone-aware datetime objects internally, and translates them to the end user’s time zone in templates and forms.

**settings.py**

1. Enabling time zone support.

```
USE_TZ = True
```

2. Enable local formatting of time

```
USE_L10N  = True
```

**[Refer to django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/timezones/#time-zones)**.